# ngIf condition switched but display isnt

Tags: angular

I have three components

componentOne

```
  public step = 'two';

  updateStep() {
    this.step = 'three';
    console.log('new step: ' + this.step);
  }

<div *ngIf="step === 'two'">
   <app-step-two></app-step-two>
</div>
<div *ngIf="step === 'three'">
   <app-step-three></app-step-three>
</div>
```

componentTwo

```
 constructor(private parent: componentOne) { }
  buttonClicked() {
     this.parent.updateStep();
  }

<div> This is two </div>
<button (click)="buttonClicked()" >test</button>
```

componentThree

```
<div> this should be displayed </div>
```

In the ComponentOne the view I can see it is initialized to view step 2. But how come the view doesnt switch to step 3 when update() is called?

edit: what I mean is

```
<div *ngIf="step === 'three'">
   <app-step-three></app-step-three>
</div>
```

suppose to be shown...but it isnt

Comment: but if I move it to a service then how do I update the first component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**componentTwo**

```
import { Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Output('updateStep') updateStep = new EventEmitter();

constructor() { }

buttonClicked() {
    this.updateStep.emit();
}

<div> This is two </div>
<button (click)="buttonClicked()" >test</button>
```

**componentOne**

```
<app-step-two (updateStep)="updateStep()"></app-step-two>
```

**Explanation**

The componentOne is a parent component for the componentTwo and componentThree.

You should use the Output method to send an event from child components to the parent component.

You don't need to inject your AppComponent to FirstComponent!

**UPD**
See [this sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zkhb6x?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: @logger I have added an example. Please take a look

Answer (score 1):

There is no `clicked` event. There is `click`. See [this sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vzs3ug).

```
@Component({
  selector: 'first',
  template: `<div> This is two </div><button (click)="buttonClicked()" >test</button>`,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class FirstComponent  {
  constructor(private parent: AppComponent) { }
  buttonClicked() {
     this.parent.updateStep();
  }
}
```